# Error occurs after I have uploaded icons for app (in Android Studio with Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have created app icons with a website called [appicon](https://appicon.co/). It provided icon files for both android(mipmap files) and ios devices(an Assets.xcassets file), which I added to their respective locations being (`C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\i_am_rich(name of app)\android\app\src\main\res`) for android and (`C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\i_am_rich\ios\Runner`) for ios.

When I run the program the following error is displayed:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\user\StudioProjects\i_am_rich\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:16: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.i_am_rich:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am learning Android Studio as the IDE with flutter, as a beginner, so I don't understand the problem nor what I have to do to fix it.

Help and, possibly, an explanation would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The website you mentioned does generate correct names and correct order of directories it seems. so most probably this is an issue with where you have put your files or the name of the files.

The 5 directories of icons must be copied to `android\app\src\main\res` folder.

and make sure in each directory you have a file called `ic_launcher`

if all is correct, please run `flutter clean` command and try again.

also by anychance the webisite generating incorrect files, try using this web site [AndroidAssetStudio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)

Comment: Thank you! The problem was in the icon generator I used,, it did not have any launchers. Do you know of any good alternative sites for ios, as well?